# Magento Store locator address not visible on iPhones - Why?

Tags: javascript, magento-1.9.2.0, google-map

I am using Google store locator for my extension

but address not visible when click the locator icons on iPhones,
i don't know what caused this issue..

It is working fine when i tried with browserstack(ios), in mobile it does not.

Can anyone faced it already...Kindly give me the suggestion.
Help me StackExchange, you're my only hope!

Comment: please contact with extension provider for this query

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asking about 2rd party extension

Comment: can you give me the suggestion what may cause this.

Comment: i think the problem may be starts here GBrowserIsCompatible()....????

Comment: sorry,i did  not know `GBrowserIsCompatible `

Comment: i got this in firebug console - Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys

Comment: i found the solution @Amit Bera

Comment: greats :)  keep posted it

Comment: Sure..thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this issue...previously i wrote marker on **"*mouseover*"** that's why was not working in iPhones....Now i changed it to **"click"**
simple change but it worked for me cool....